# asyncronously pulling large data from pyodbc using fetchmany

Tags: python-asyncio, pyodbc

I am trying to pull a large dataset from `pyodbc`. My code below works ok, but it is serial, hence slow. I want to make it able to initiate multiple IO calls asynchronously. I see many examples using `asyncio` - but cannot find anything i can use with `fetchmany`. I appreciate any suggestions! I attempted to pool using `asyncio` but couldn't make it work.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=Denodo Interfaces')
cursor = conn.cursor()  
strng = strng.replace('myWellName', well_name)
cursor.execute(strng)

cols = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
mylist=[]

while True:
    rows = cursor.fetchmany(10000)
    if not rows:
        break
    df = pd.DataFrame([tuple(t) for t in rows], columns = cols)
    mylist.append(df)

df = pd.concat(mylist, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: asyncio requires the use of async libraries - for ODBC that might be [aioodbc](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioodbc). Then you can easily launch multiple coroutines in parallel, e.g. using [`loop.create_task(your_coroutine())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_task).

Comment: thanks! i will explore this